# How to read a graph representing the stabilizers and data qubits in surface code

Tags: error-correction, surface-code

I am trying to understand to properly read the graph below, provided in [this post](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23653/how-do-we-create-logical-qubits-in-the-surface-code-understanding-check/23663?noredirect=1#comment31032_23663)

[image]

It is said that the black elements are the $Z$ stabilizers and the grey ones are the $X$ stabilizers. I am trying to make a connection with the physical positions of the data and measurement qubits. Below is my attempt (but I am confused).

[image]

The white circles with a red contour are data qubit, fully black circles are $Z$-measurement qubits, white circles (with a black contour) are $X$-measurement qubits.

As you see, even by rotating of $45°$ the physical surface (given below) I cannot reproduce the upper pattern properly. For instance the $Z$ stabilizers at the boundaries are only connected to two data qubits (instead of three).

Hence, how to understand properly the upper representation in connection to the physical world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each bulb becomes an outside corner and each side-square because an inside corner. You get a zig-zaggy pattern of cuts:

[image: overlaid plots]